# How to pause a CarouFredSel carousel from clicking a thumbnail

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, caroufredsel

Continuing in my unlimited questions using CarouFredSel:

I have a set of thumbnails which control a carousel. Here is a link to a previous qestion I had in how to set it up:

[caroufredsel image thumbnail pagination in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189869/caroufredsel-image-thumbnail-pagination-in-wordpress)

And another question as to how to pause it when the thumb is clicked

[pause carousel on click caroufredsel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449646/pause-carousel-on-click-caroufredsel)

My solution was to add a delay.

All works dandy until you click on another thumbnail. Nothing happens. It has something to do with the pause / delay I think. As if I remove the timeout function, it fades to each thumbnail that is clicked...but no longer pauses the slideshow on each click of the thumbnail.

```
$('#thumbs .thumb a').each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass( 'itm'+i );

        /* add onclick event to thumbnail to make the main 
        carousel scroll to the right slide*/
        $(this).click(function() {

                $('#project-carousel').trigger( 'slideTo', [i, 0, true] );
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#project-carousel').trigger('pause', true);
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
        });
    });
```

To summarize, this works fine when you click any thumbnail the first time, subsequent clicks of any thumbnail do nothing. It's like I can't start the slideshow up again.

I thought of some conditional statements, but each one I can think of applies to each instance, not one from a subsequent click. Something like this:

```
if($(this).not(".paused")) {
       $('#project-carousel').trigger( 'slideTo', [i, 0, true] );
       }
       else {
        $(this).addClass("paused");
       $('#project-carousel').trigger( 'slideTo', [i, 0, true] );
            setTimeout(function() {
           $('#project-carousel').trigger('pause', true);
            }, 1000);
             return false;
        }
```

but alas, that just always hits that first condition and does not make it to the else, thus not pausing. I think it is just maybe a logic problem, but maybe its just a trigger I need to add to kickstart the carousel again. Don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a delay issue. This is the code resolved:

```
jQuery(function(){

    $(".project-arrows").click(function() {
        $('#project-carousel').trigger('play',true);
    });

    /* Attached an unique class name to each thumbnail image */
    $('#thumbs .thumb a').each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass( 'itm'+i );

        /* add onclick event to thumbnail to make the main 
        carousel scroll to the right slide*/
        $(this).click(function() {
            $('#project-carousel').trigger('play',true);
            $('#project-carousel').trigger( 'slideTo', [i, 0, true] );
            $('#project-carousel').trigger('stop');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

The trick was to use stop instead of pause, and on any click trigger the play.